# ObjC vs. MonoTouch float and array performance

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

**EDIT :** Added `unsafe` version of C# code. Thank you guys for this suggestion, the `unsafe` C# code runs faster, but only about 3%.

---

**Short version:** I wrote some benchmark code in C# and in Objective-C and tested it on the iPad 3. The MonoTouch/C# version needed between 50%-150% more time to execute than the same code in Objective-C. Here's my question: **Can I write C# code which executes faster than the code I used for the benchmark (see below), or is this caused by some inherent MonoTouch/Obj-C difference?**

---

**Long version:** I just wrote a small prototype for a planned multi-platform game. After porting the game core from Windows/.NET to the iPad 3/MonoTouch, I noticed how much slower the code ran on the iPad. Certain crucial parts of the game core ran about 10 times slower on the iPad CPU than on the Intel CPU (which seems to be normal because the iPad runs with an ARM processor).

However, since this is a major problem for our game, I ran a small benchmark test on the iPad 3, once with **MonoTouch**, and then the same thing with plain **Objective-C**. The benchmark does a lot of simple `float` additions and `float` array lookups. Since MonoTouch is GC'ed, I expected to see a small difference in favor of Obj-C, but to my astonishment, the MonoTouch code needed much more time to run than the Obj-C code. To be precise:

- The **Obj-C** code needed `47'647 ms` to run in DEBUG mode, and `27'162 ms` in RELEASE mode.
- The **MonoTouch** code without the use of `unsafe` pointers needed `116'885 ms` to run in DEBUG mode, and `40'002 ms` in RELEASE mode.
- The **MonoTouch** code **with `unsafe` pointers** needed `90'372 ms` to run in DEBUG mode, and `38'764 ms` in RELEASE mode.

Of course, the RELEASE mode is what I care about.

This difference seems a bit high to me, given the fact that MonoTouch compiles to the same native `LLVM` code as Obj-C.

Here is the Obj-C code I used:

```
int i, j;
long time = GetTimeMs64();
float * arr = (float *) malloc(10000 * sizeof(float)); //  10'000
for (j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {                         // 100'000
    arr[0] = 0;
    arr[1] = 1;
    for (i = 2; i < 10000; i++) {                      //  10'000
        arr[i] = arr[i - 2] + arr[i - 1];
        if (arr[i] > 2000000000) {             // prevent arithm. overflow
            arr[i - 1] = 0;
            arr[i] = 1;
        }
    }
}
long time2 = GetTimeMs64() - time;
```

`GetTimeMs64()` uses `<sys/time.h>`'s `gettimeofday`.

Here my C#/MonoTouch code, in the `unsafe` version:

```
var array = new float[10000];                          //  10'000
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
fixed (float* arr = array)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++)                   // 100'000
    {
        *(arr + 0) = 0;
        *(arr + 1) = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < 10000; i++)                //  10'000
        {
            *(arr + i) = *(arr + i - 2) + *(arr + i - 1);
            if (*(arr + i) > 2000000000)               // prevent arithm. overflow
            {
                *(arr + i - 1) = 0;
                *(arr + i) = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

watch.Stop();
```

**EDIT 2:** This is the answer we got from Xamarin:

> There are two issues with this particular example that impair mono
>   performance.
>
> First, if you're using the default MonoTouch compiler, and not LLVM,
>   you can expect lower performance as it's tunned for compilation speed
>   and not execution speed. LLVM will give you better results.
>
> Second, mono complies with the ECMA spec regarding floating point and
>   does all computations with double precision. This usually have a
>   measurable performance cost specially if compared to C code using
>   floats.
>
> We've been looking into ways to relax the double precision performance
>   without compromising correctness or, at least, have an opt in
>   mechanism.

Comment: Does monotouch allow "unsafe"? You could do all of that with a `float*` - should be noticeably faster...?

Comment: thank you, unfortunately it's only about 3% faster..

Comment: @cheeesus What did you decide to use in the end?

Answer (score 5):

Like Marc suggested you should use `unsafe` code, MonoTouch supports this .NET feature.

That will remove the .NET array-bounds checks which are **a nice, safer, feature of .NET** but has performance penalties (since each array access **must** be checked).

That will make your code looks more (both in source and natively) looks like the Objective-C code and performance should be closer. Still I advice you to use `unsafe` code only when performance really matters (and after measuring that the gain are worth it).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the unsafe C# code is only about 3% faster. I edited the code to reflect the `unsafe` changes, and I added the new benchmark results. I'm still looking for other solutions.

Comment: `unsafe` allows you to remove the `[]` array indices (using pointers) which will remove the ABC (array bounds checking) that takes the extra time.

Comment: OTOH I did not see any real improvement using pointers. I suggest you to contact support@xamarin.com with your test case so someone from the runtime can look at what code is being generated.

Comment: Thank you Sebastien, I'm using pointers now, but the execution time is still `38'819 ms` compared to `27'162 ms` in ObjC.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to contact support@xamarin.com